# setting up project with Yarn 4 pnp, webpack and typescript

Tags: typescript, webpack, yarnpkg

I am trying to set up my project with Yarn and webpack and typescript. You can see the code below. The problem I have is that when I import another `.ts` file, it gives me an error and can't resolve the path.

`Package.json`

```
{
  "name": "my-name",
  "packageManager": "yarn@4.0.2",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rm -rf dist && webpack",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "js-sha256": "^0.10.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "pnp-webpack-plugin": "^1.7.0",
    "ts-loader": "^9.5.1",
    "typescript": "^5.3.2",
    "webpack": "^5.89.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
  }
}
```

`webpack.config.js`

```
const path = require("path");
const PnpWebpackPlugin = require(`pnp-webpack-plugin`);

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.ts",
  devtool: "inline-source-map",
  mode: "production",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: "ts-loader",
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"],
  },
  output: {
    filename: "main.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
  },
  resolve: {
    plugins: [PnpWebpackPlugin],
  },
  resolveLoader: {
    plugins: [PnpWebpackPlugin.moduleLoader(module)],
  },
};
```

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "ES6",
    "allowJs": true,
    "moduleResolution": "Node"
  },
  "exclude": ["./webpack.config.js", "./dist/**/*"]
}
```

when I do the import, I get the below error

```
// index.ts
import { sha256 } from "js-sha256";
import { testFunc } from "./myFile.js";
testFunc();


// myFile.ts
export function testFunc(){
 console.log('test')
}
```

`Error`

```
ERROR in ./src/index.ts 49:0-39
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './myFile.js' in '__root_project__/src'
resolve './myFile.js' in '__root_project__/src'
  using description file: __root_project__/package.json (relative path: ./src)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    using description file: __root_project__/package.json (relative path: ./src/myFile.js)
      no extension
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        __root_project__/src/myFile.js doesn't exist
      .js
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        __root_project__/src/myFile.js.js doesn't exist
      .json
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        __root_project__/src/myFile.js.json doesn't exist
      .wasm
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        __root_project__/src/myFile.js.wasm doesn't exist
      as directory
        __root_project__/src/myFile.js doesn't exist

webpack 5.89.0 compiled with 1 error in 796 ms
```

also when I import with `.ts` extension the typescript wants me to set `noEmit` to true and so on which causes more problem for me, specially using yarn pnp.